# Calling a variable and list to another class?

Tags: c#, variables

I am learning c# and I've stumbled on an issue. I've tried looking around on google to call variables onto another class. What I've found is by using the get set method. Is this the only way of doing so?

Another question is, how do I then retrieve information from a list to br printed to another class.

The code I did can be found below.

```
class Program
{
    public int Xyz { get; set; } = 15;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        List<int> Lst = new List<int>();

        Lst.Add(1);
        Lst.Add(2);
        Lst.Add(3);

        for (int x = 0; x < Lst.Count; x++)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is number {0}.", Lst[x]);
        }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        public void Next(int Xyz)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value of Xyz is: {0}", Xyz);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Lst.Count);
            List<int> Lst2 = new List<int>(Lst);
            Console.WriteLine("Lst2 has {0} values.", Lst2.Count);
        }
    }

}
```

What I wanted to see from

`Console.WriteLine("Value of Xyz is: {0}", Xyz);`is the value 15.

and from

`Console.WriteLine("{0}", Lst.Count);` the value 3.

Thank you very much! <3

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Enko78

Comment: mjwills's method is ok. I provide another method by using static class PublicZoom. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        PulicZoom.Lst.Add(1);
        PulicZoom.Lst.Add(2);
        PulicZoom.Lst.Add(3);

        for (int x = 0; x < PulicZoom.Lst.Count; x++)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is number {0}.", PulicZoom.Lst[x]);
        }

        Tests test = new Tests();
        test.Next();
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        public void Next()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value of Xyz is: {0}", PulicZoom.Xyz);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", PulicZoom.Lst.Count);
            List<int> Lst2 = new List<int>(PulicZoom.Lst);
            Console.WriteLine("Lst2 has {0} values.", Lst2.Count);
        }
    }

    public static class PulicZoom
    {
        public static int Xyz { get; set; } = 15;
        public static List<int> Lst = new List<int>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Charles, I've implemented the modified code and i must say that it looks much cleaner when the variable and list that I want to call are declared in another class. Thank you very much for the code. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Nate ready to help any time. If you accept my answer, it would be better.

Comment: I think some explanation is needed here even if it is the answer. How does this solve the problem? A little more explanation would really improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should learn about basic object oriented concepts, including the scope of variables. Notice that your Lst is created within the function 'main'. This means that the name 'Lst' is only valid within this function. Since your Tests class exists outside the function, it cannot access the variable.

Additionally, you defined the function Next(int xyz) within tests. Firstly, this xyz will shadow the name of the outer xyz as they share the same name. This means whenever you refer to xyz, you are only referring to the xyz passed into the function as a variable, and not the xyz outside. Furthermore, the function is never called anywhere. As such, it will not be run. Since the function resides inside the test class, you need to create an instance of the test object first using "Test t = new Test();", then subsequently call the function using "t.Next();"

Comment: Hi Arch, I will do so as I am still learning. Thank you for explaining my errors!